# Access data created by WebView in the Activity

Tags: android

I have an HTML page which uses local storage to store some data. I'm wondering if it is even possible to access the data (created by web view) outside of the web view, for example from an activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a an Object that will be accessible via javascript using [WebView.addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).  Then call one of the methods from JavaScript passing it the stored data.  When called, you can access that data from the method called in the Object you added to the WebView.